# How can I convert multiple columns data to single row data using Pandas pivot function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Greetings of the day!!

I have a pandas Dataframe like below:

| A | 2022-Mar | 2022-Apr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 222 |
| 2 | 333 | 444 |

I am expecting resultant dataframe like below:

| A | MonthYear | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-Mar | 111 |
| 1 | 2022-Apr | 222 |
| 2 | 2022-Mar | 333 |
| 2 | 2022-Apr | 444 |

Please help me with this!

I can achieve this using Pandas Stack method, but i have to do this using Pandas pivot method.

Note: In resultant table i have to create column names as well.

Thanks in advance!

I have tried pandas stack method and i have achieved this... But my requirement is like to do with pandas pivot method.

**Tried method:**

newDF = df.set_index('A') .stack().rename(columns{'level_1':'MonthYear',0:'Quantity'})

display(newDF)

Comment: It is unpivot, so need `melt`, not `pivot`

Comment: Hey @jezrael, Thanks for this solution... It seems good but i am not getting the desired output... It is giving me the result like |A| --> 1 2 1 2, but i need like 1 1 2 2. So what should be done? Could you help? I have tried so many methods to sort but didn't help.

Comment: If dont want use `stack` use`melt` with `sort_values(['A'])`